# Why doesn't Rogue have super strength and the ability to fly?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine-and-the-x-men, rogue

In the animated series *Wolverine and the X-Men*, why doesn't Rogue have the abilities of Ms. Marvel?

The Wikipedia page on the series links the characters to their main Wikipedia entries, which says that Rogue got the powers of Ms. Marvel when she was a young woman. The series seems to take place sometime after the X-Men were already established, then disbanded, and starts off with them attempting to reform the X-Men.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After the [***X-Men*** film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_%28film%29) was released in 2000, Rogue's Ms. Marvel powers have been shelved in favor of presenting a streamlined character.

This makes sense, as trying to explain that this new mutant has already fought a superhero named Ms. Marvel, who is also an Avenger, who also has powers from an alien species (the Kree) would provide way too much story to cover in one movie, especially considering that nearly every character in the X-Men movies have equally complex backstories. Rogue's origin was simplified and her natural power (not being able to touch anyone and absorbing powers) is simple and ripe with story/drama potential.

As the X-Men film introduced a whole new generation to her, probably giving her even more exposure than the [early '90s cartoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_%281992_TV_series%29), it made sense to present her this way in *[**X-Men: Evolution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Evolution)* (2000). If Rogue had shown up with super strength and flight, she would have been drastically different than the public saw her the summer before in a blockbuster movie.

Meanwhile in the comics, the powers Rogue absorbed from Ms. Marvel were stripped away. Her powers were mutated in the comics by an alien ([*X-Men* #107, December 2000](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=4233)), which eventually led her to having every power she had ever absorbed, to then having no powers at all, to finally only having her natural born absorption powers. She currently only has her natural powers.

Rogue was depicted without Ms. Marvel's powers in both ***X2*** (2003) and ***X-Men: The Last Stand*** (2006), further solidifying the version without Ms. Marvel's powers in the public consciousness.

When [***Wolverine and the X-Men***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_and_the_X-Men) started in early 2009, it aimed to be more in line with the comics than the films. Even though the series was going to be further removed from the film series that had always shown Rogue without Ms. Marvel's powers, at that point it would be weird and confusing to give Rogue powers that she hadn't had in the *comics* for almost a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in this continuity she hasn't absorbed Ms. Marvel's powers?

IIRC, she absorbed them while acting as a villain, under the guidance of Mystique.  Lacking villainy* or Mystique's 'loving' care*, she may never have been in a position to do so.

*I haven't seen this show, so I don't know if this is the case.

Answer (score -2):

Because Fox legally couldn't make Rogue's back story with the Danvers story, as Danvers wasn't a mutant. As for the cartoons, I'm not sure. They did in X-Men TAS, without explanation.

Eventually she had her Danvers powers and personality stripped during Messiah Complex. Although now she has Wonder Man's powers. So who knows.

Comment: Fox has changed other mutant's powers, so they could have easily changed Rogue's or given it some other explanation.

Comment: They haven't changed them that dramatically. Besides, we're talking back when studios just made them to keep them and they weren't taken as seriously. 

Also Rogue didn't always have Danvers powers. And Rogue in the movie was intended to be a child, much like iceman and Kitty Pryde. So technically they just used pre Danvers power up Rogue.

Answer (score -5):

Because they are not using her like they should from the comic story lines.

They cannot make her with this flight power and super strong nigh invulnerable either because it would be too hard for one without making her almost totally a digital character and because her story is kept secret from most when those who know about her know she was adopted by Mystique in disguise and she did at one time call her Mama.

She was part of the Brotherhood at that time as well until Mystique basically forced her to stay connected to Ms Marvel for as long as she did because something in Mystique told her that Rogue would keep the powers from someone if she stayed touching them longer. It really only made sense to her but Rogue was not ready for that burden and ultimately left her in search of help from Professor X.

How did that work out for her? Well not entirely well as she could have hoped but she is a great person, a compassionate woman and a badass fighting bitch so a welcome member of the team now.

Comment: Hmm - Are you sure you can use "nigh invulnerable" here? I thought Cannonball (or maybe the Tick) had trademarked that. :-)